# Boosted regression trees - Errors

Tags: r

I use BRT to analyze the variable Land surface temperature through 10 predictive variables（include building volume,FAR,High...）. All the data are numerical, but why are there errors in the running results

```
total mean deviance =  NaN 
tolerance is fixed at  NaN 
ntrees resid. dev. 
50    NaN 
now adding trees... 
Error in while (delta.deviance > tolerance.test & n.fitted < max.trees) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In log(1 - u_i) : NaNs produced
```

[image: R output with errors]

Comment: Welcome to SO, XXin!  You will be most likely to get your question answered if you follow the [helpful advice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about asking questions and create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are there occurences where u_i > 1?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the meaning of this error(include "u_i")